# How to write a VBS Script to Repair a Corrupted Excel File?

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, corrupt

How can we write a VBS Script to repair an invalid sheet name in Excel?

When we open the file in Excel, we get three dialog boxes, presenting us with errors - the third being the 'Repairs to 'Bad.xls''.

My question is, how can we write a VBS Script to do this automatically so that we can process large numbers of files?

Comment: it might be good to know what is creating the invalid names, perhaps you could prevent the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you can't find the vba syntax do do something you start recording a macro, do the thing you want to automate, stop the macro and examine the VBA code, you should be able to extract what you want from there. Success !

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is how to recover corrupted XLS with method open corrupted data, do some normalization, then write into fixed XLS.

If that most important function above is found and proven, then using it to process many files is just as simply as automatic loop or based on specific list of files.